# How can Android developers verify the integrity of apps delivered through the Play Store?

Tags: android, security, google-play, android-app-bundle, data-integrity

Please, note this is NOT the same as [What Stops Google From Modifying Our APKs That It Signs Via the App Signing Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705739/what-stops-google-from-modifying-our-apks-that-it-signs-via-the-app-signing-serv)
The above merely asks what is stopping Google from modifying apps - the answer there is "nothing".  *My* question is: given that Google does not provide a process that guarantees integrity, what measures can developers take (on their own) to provide themselves a means of verification?

**Background:**

When a developer publishes an app to the Play Store as an APK file, the developer signs the APK before upload.  This signature can be used to verify that the APK a user downloads from the Play Store was built by the developer, and that it hasn't been altered in any way since the developer built it.  The developer also can publish a hash/checksum of the APK file to verify file integrity.

[image: developer generates and signs APK, and Play Store delivers that file unaltered to user]

To quote the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure_key):

> If you allow someone to use your key, or if you leave your keystore
> and passwords in an unsecured location such that a third-party could
> find and use them, your authoring identity and the trust of the user
> are compromised.
>
> If a third party should manage to take your key without your knowledge
> or permission, that person could sign and distribute apps that
> maliciously replace your authentic apps or corrupt them. Such a person
> could also sign and distribute apps under your identity that attack
> other apps or the system itself, or corrupt or steal user data.

So clearly it's extremely important that developers do not allow third parties to access their private signing keys.

However, when a developer publishes an app to the Play Store using the Android App Bundle format (aab), the file that users download is not produced and signed by the developer, but rather, by the Play Store.

[image: developer uploads app bundle to Play Store, then Play Store generated and signs different APKs for different devices]

In this model, neither signatures nor hashes can be used to verify that the app is unmodified.  The Play Store could theoretically add to/remove from/alter the files provided by the developer, and target individual users with different alterations.

The Play Store has announced that as of August 2021, all new apps will be required to use the AAB delivery format.  **Once this policy is in place, what alternative method can developers use for accountability and verification of the integrity of the apps they publish?**

Comment: The bounty answer specifically covers this "Lastly, I'll mention integrity checks as one way this would be discovered. There are several solutions in this space that goes further than signature checks to verify the integrity of the app. Whether app developers roll their own, or use an off-the-shelves solution- these checks typically run during runtime on device to verify the integrity of the apk; comparing against records taken during compile-time or near compile-time. Modifications performed to the apk during transit does get picked up by this, including whatever change Google Play might do."

Comment: @ianhanniballake "comparing against records taken during compile-time or near compile-time" - this is pretty vague.  I don't think this meets the standard for answers on SO

Comment: @duggulous The question that this answer was written for wasn't "how to perform integrity check of apk/aab files", and so isn't vague nor below standard considering the context and question it was written for.

But to elaborate on this bit- during compile-time or near compile-time would be either during the creation of the apk file (with a gradle script or plugin for instance), or right after it's creation, before upload to Google play. At this time you can inspect the apk or bundle file and its contents, and create records that you later compare to runtime.